# Azure Functions V2 DI - Configuration

Tags: azure-functions

I am using [this microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) to configure a function.

I want to pull in some settings from my `local.appsettings.json` but by default the Provider Sources only includes `appsettings.json`. If I add an appsettings.json file to the project it does not appear to read it - I suspect because it's reading a global one from some other location.

If I add a configuration for `local.appsettings.json` in my Startup.Configure method then it ***seems to replace completely the default configuration sources***.

Is the use of `local.appsettings.json` just generally discouraged now in favour of environment variables?

Is there a way for me to just add my configuration to the default list?

#### UPDATE

What I am trying to achieve overall is to load a connection string within the `Configure()` method of my custom `Startup` class.

### Clarification

Thanks for the answers however my question is subtly different. I know I can add a configuration for `local.appsettings.json` but in my Configure method if I have:

```
builder.Services.Configure<MyFuncOptions>(MyLocalConfigurationRoot);
```

it will nuke out the `ChainedConfigurationProvider`, `MemoryConfigurationProvider`, `JsonConfigurationProvider`, and `EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvder` that were added by the host. I wanted to add mine to the existing list of providers.

I have since read that this is not possible.

### Final Solution

Thanks to Marc's and Bowman's answers I persevered with their suggestions (and up-voted them) and ended up with a custom `FunctionsStartup` class and a `FuncOptions` class to inject into functions. This allowed me to load configuration during startup to use to configure services and then be able to use them elsewhere. Apologies that my question was somewhat poorly framed in the first place.

```cs
public class FunctionsStartp : Startup
{
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            IConfiguration configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
                .Build();

            builder.Services.Configure<FuncOptions>(configurationRoot.GetSection("Values"));

            var athenaConn = configurationRoot["Values:AthenaConnectionString"];

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<AthenaContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(athenaConn);
            });
        }
    }
}

public class GetNewPlunetOrders
{
    private readonly IOptions<FuncOptions> _opts;

    public GetNewOrders(IOptions<FuncOptions> opts) { _opts = opts; }

    [FunctionName(nameof(GetNewOrders))]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, 
            ILogger log)
    {
        ...
        var d = _opts.Value.AthenaConnectionString;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Have my solution solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The place to put your settings on your local machine would be the`local.settings.json` file. Here's an example where I added a TableStorageConnection (in this case it's using emulated storage locally):

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "TableStorageConnection": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  }
}
```

In your code you then retrieve the connectionstring with this method:

```cs
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TableStorageConnection")
```

When you publish/release your function to Azure you still need to configure the production connection string as an application setting though one of these methods:

- [The portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings). Not recommended since this is a manual procedure and can be overwritten with a new deployment.
- [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#examples). A bit better than setting it through the portal.
- In the release pipeline. For instance when using Azure DevOps you can use the [Function Azure App Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-function-app?view=azure-devops) and set the appSettings there. This woul be my recommended approach.

I really prefer using the `GetEnvironmentVariable` method so I don't need path references which will vary from machine to machine (local vs cloud).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Marc but if you see my Clarification heading added to my question, the question is actually slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the Connecting String from `local.setting.json`:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath("D:\\Users\\bowmanzh\\source\\repos\\FunctionApp7\\FunctionApp2")
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
var appParameter = "AzureWebJobsStorage";
string appsetting = config[$"{appParameter}"];
```

The value in the `SetBasePath` is the url where your `local.setting.json` in, and this is my `local.setting.json` code:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxw==;BlobEndpoint=https://bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxnimagestorage02.file.core.windows.net/",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

If you just want to get the connection string in the `local.settings.json`, Only use the code that I show to you is enough. On my side, I get the connection string. If you have more questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BowmanZhu but if you see my Clarification heading added to my question, the question is actually different.